# Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908) verr_vm_driver_not_installed

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I use Ubuntu 17.10, but I can't run any VM.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing
>
> '/sbin/vboxconfig'
>
> as root.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

I have run `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`, but nothing happened.

Comment: It works, I use it. Have you enabled Virtual Technology in the Bios?

Comment: Yes, i did that. But i still can't run it.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, the problem has been solved. According to this article [virtualbox+Secure Boot+ubuntu=fail](https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail/), you may need to install the package `virtualbox-ext-pack`.